# TCL lsearch behaviour

Tags: tcl

Weird problem with lsearch not behaving. I am probably doing something stupid. Any ideas/help would be very much appreciated!

```
set mylist {}

lappend mylist a
lappend mylist b
lappend mylist c

set test [lsearch -exact mylist b]
puts "This doesn't work, result should be 1 = $test"

set test2 [lsearch {a b c d e} c]
puts "This works, result should be 2 = $test2"
```

Answer (score 6):

You're searching for a list that contains a single element:

```
{mylist}
```

You need to pass the variable `mylist` instead:

```
lsearch -exact $mylist b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the element...

```
set my_split_list [split $mylist]
```

However this will give you all sorts of crazy subsitution syntax such as {, ", \ etc in your new my_split_list.